# Redirect to login page after session finished

Tags: javascript, php

i have a website for e-voting. i want to make user back to login page after they finished their voting session. After voting has finished, it always come back to the same page. and its only happen in mozilla firefox browser. i have tried it in another browser like microsoft edge and google chrome, and its all works fine, except in mozilla firefox.

Here is the javascript code.

```
<script type="application/x-javascript"> 
    
    function balik(e){
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/logout",
          data: null
        });
        window.location="/index.php";
    }
    
</script>
```

this is the php code

```
class Pilih_mpm extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('login')) {
            redirect('admin');
        }

        if ($this->session->userdata('login_user')) {
            redirect('pilih_mpm/calon');
            $this->load->view('user/v_verif');
        }       
            
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('pilih');
    }

}
```

I think the problem is in `verif()` function in php code or `balik()` function in javascript code, but i keep changing it and nothing changes.

here is the method in `pilih.php`

```
public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_pilih');
        $this->load->model('m_admin');
        // $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('login')) {
            redirect('admin');
        }

        if ($this->session->userdata('login_user')) {
            redirect('pilih/calon');
        }       
        $this->load->view('user/v_verif');  
    }
```

Thank you very much for anyone help

Comment: I suspect `application/x-javascript`

Comment: whats wrong with that? should I remove it? @Viney

Comment: It's a non-standard syntax try removing type attribute entirely like `<script> </script>`

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work @Viney

Comment: Why do you have this `redirect('pilih');` in logout?. What does this redirect to?

Comment: that should redirect to `pilih` where it load the login view @Aashishgaba

Comment: Okay, can you share the code for that method ?

Comment: Oh, no no, don't add it as an answer, delete the answer. Update it in the post itself.

Comment: i have done it @Aashishgaba

Comment: Okay, great. Add a printing statement inside the logout, index as well as in js after the ajax call, to see if the workflow(redirection on calling the logout route) is fine or not.